# Referring the object in JSON and what is nested

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

I am currently trying to test my backend by doing an HTTP post request by send the following JSON object. The only way I can refer "NPG" and the "name" key and its value in React is if I do console.log(req.body.NPG) and console.log(req.body.NPG.name). The problems lies if instead of sending "NPG" like "SPG", then my console logs would give me an undefined error. How do I refer to "NPG" generically? I tried doing console.log(req.body.object) but I still have the undefined error. My end goal is to save the JSON object to a MongoDB collection.

```
\\JSON object
{
  "NPG":{
    "name": "North Parking Garage",
    "desc" "6-story parking structure located on the corner of S. 10th and E.  San Fernando Streets"
  }
}

\\My Model Schema

const testSchema = new Schema({
  object: {
    name: String,
    desc: String,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code will not break.

```
req && req.body && req.body.NPG && console.log(req.body.NPG.name);

for SPG

req && req.body && req.body.SPG && console.log(req.body.SPG.name)
```